# CPP console, when closing, open another cpp file

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a text based console game, using C++ and Window's command prompt. Visual studio makes my life easy, but I cannot find a way to go from the Start Menu.cpp to the Level 1.cpp file, once the first file closes

```
#include "Header.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
using namespace std;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    //intro menu
        std::string name;
        cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
        cin >> name;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "\nHello " << name << ", ";
        cout << "welcome to the AdventureBox!" << endl;
        system("pause");

        cin.ignore();
        //open level 1 file
}
```

I know I should use return 0; but that doesn't seem to work with entering your name. So that's just the main menu, but I want it to open the next file

I there something I am supposed to do in the header?

```
#pragma once
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
using namespace std;
string name;
```

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of functions in C++? You might want to write a level1 function and just call it at the end of your current main().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how control flow works. `main.cpp` is where all code is executed and function calls are made. You can make a function that starts level 1 in a separate header file.

Like so:

`level1.h`

```
void levelone()
{
    //level 1 code here...
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "level1.h"

int main()
{
    //Menu stuff...
    levelone();
    //rest of code...
}
```

You could even make a separate thread for level 1 if you wanted, I wouldn't recommend this since you're new to C/C++.

I HIGHLY recommend you learn more about control flow. Find a good tutorial series on YouTube like Bucky or something. Or you could pay for a course to learn the basic syntax. Don't make the same mistakes I did by skipping basic syntax and concepts because you will do things the hard way or won't be able to do them at all because of lack of knowledge.

Good luck on learning and making your game.

Comment: I just cut & pasted my "first level" code into the "menu" .cpp file for now, but thank you, I will look into flow and syntax, to further expand my knowledge, and hopefully not have the whole game in one file XD

Comment: @Snakeblood I'd watch a few more tutorials about classes, macros, header files, etc. But I'm glad to see the interest. Just stay at it. Good luck!